# I am getting undefined for attr on form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason i am getting undefined trying to get the attr of an element. Not sure what i might be doing wrong here.

Here is code:

```
var $lastFormGroupLast = $multipleFormGroup.find('.form-group:last');
    $id = $lastFormGroupLast.attr('id');
    c = $id.substr($id.length - 1);
    c = parseInt(c);
    $formGroupClone.attr('id', 'id'+(++c) );
    $formGroupClone.insertAfter($formGroup);
```

Here is the html:

```
<form id="id0" class="form-group multiple-form-group input-group form-inline" style="width: 585px;">
                        <div class="input-group">
                          <div class="input-group-addon">http://</div>
                          <input style="width: 170px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="url[]" class="form-control pull-left web_url" placeholder="type website url">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input style="width: 95px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="url[]" class="form-control pull-left width" placeholder="1024px">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input style="width: 95px; margin-right: 5px;" type="text" name="url[]" class="form-control pull-left height" placeholder="600px">
                        </div>
                        <input class="thathidden" type="hidden" name="base_id" value="<?php echo $deet[0]->id; ?>">        
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-alert btngrab">Grab</button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-add">Add New</button>
                        </span>
                    </form>
```

Comment: it means your element doesnt have that attribute defined

Comment: ... or the collection is empty.

Comment: If possible , can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: You are leaking global variables all over the place. Unless this is intentional (for some crazy reason), you should 'var' up your local variables. Also, how come you're prefixing your variables with $? That's usually reserved for certain frameworks etc. Will confusing to others.

Comment: @Tapha Appear to be _1_ `id` within `html` , `id0` at `form` element. Rendering `:last` equivalent to `:first` . With `id0` , `$id.substr($id.length - 1);` would return `d0` . Try `"id0".substr(-1) // 0` , though not appear where `$formGroupClone` is defined ?